# In sequelize connection I am getting operation timeout error. How to fix this issue

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, sequelize-typescript, sequelize-hooks

I am using Sequelize ORM for connecting databases using NODE JS and PostgreSQL. When I request concurrently to the server it's throwing an error **ConnectionAcquireTimeoutError [SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError]: Operation timeout**. So, I search it how to fix this issue. many of the given solutions to increase to acquire count or increase the connection pool count. is it the right solution?

**Sequalize Config**

```
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
```

**Sequelize Version : 6.6.2**

**When I increase the acquire count and connection pool count it's throwing same error**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the param retry in Sequelize option to handle what to do if you got this error

```
 retry: {
    match: [/Deadlock/i, Sequelize.ConnectionError], // Retry on connection errors
    max: 3, // Maximum retry 3 times
    backoffBase: 3000, // Initial backoff duration in ms. Default: 100,
    backoffExponent: 1.5, // Exponent to increase backoff each try. Default: 1.1
  },
```

Also, there is a **tricky** thing with Sequelize, if you use transactions (I think you do) you should not use await/async but promise transactions

If your transaction use await/async, your maximum concurrent transaction will be your pool.max value, so any n+1 transaction will be rejected by a deadlock

If your transaction use Promise, your n+1 transaction will be *queued* (more delayed than queued) and will not be deadlocked

https://lightrun.com/answers/sequelize-sequelize-deadlock-on-multiple-transactions

it should solve some of your problem :)